# how to group a list of events by year, month, date

Tags: groovy

Need some help converting data returned from:

```
def groupedResults = searchResults.groupBy{it.eventYear}{it.eventMonth}{it.eventStartDate};
```

The above code currently returns:

```
[2017: [ July: [ 07/17/2017: [ [eventName: TestEvent1, eventStartDatetime: 2017-07-17 12:00:00Z], [eventName: TestEvent2, eventStartDatetime: 2017-07-17 1:00:00Z] ], [07/18/2017: [ [eventName: TestEvent3, eventStartDatetime: 2017-07-17 12:00:00Z],...],...],...]
```

I need the following:

```
[yearList: [yearValue: 2017, monthList: [ monthValue: July, dateList: [ dateValue: 07/21/2017, events: [ eventTitle: TestEvent, eventStartDatetime: 2017-07-17 12:00:00Z],...],...],...]....]
```

How can I create the data output as described?

Comment: An example of your `searchResults` would help...

Comment: Example of searchResults: [ [xEventStartDateTime:2017-07-17 12:00:00Z, xEventEndDateTime:2017-08-07 21:00:00Z, eventTitle:National Funeral Directors Association (NFDA) Conference, eventYear:2017, eventMonth:07July, eventStartDate:07/17/2017, htmlContent:<p>National Funeral Directors Association (NFDA) Conference</p>],.....]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a bit of work, I got an example input (real example input is always nice in a question btw, as it makes it easier to see what you have.  Two things are important in a journey, where you start and where you want to finish):

```
import java.time.*
import java.time.format.*

def parse = { s ->
    LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssVV'))
}

def searchResults = [
    [xEventStartDateTime:parse('2017-07-17 12:00:00Z'), eventTitle:'National Funeral Directors Association (NFDA) Conference'],
    [xEventStartDateTime:parse('2017-07-24 12:00:00Z'), eventTitle:'Gathering of Warlocks'],
    [xEventStartDateTime:parse('2018-02-17 12:00:00Z'), eventTitle:'Goose worriers meetup'],
    [xEventStartDateTime:parse('2017-01-17 12:00:00Z'), eventTitle:'The new year angering of optometrists']
]
```

We can then group them as you currently have:

```
// Group as normal
def grouped = searchResults.groupBy(
    { it.xEventStartDateTime.year }, 
    { it.xEventStartDateTime.month }, 
    {it.xEventStartDateTime.toLocalDate() }
)
```

Then, we just need a simple re-organising step to get this grouped map into the format you want:

```
// Then modify to the format you want
def result = [
    yearList: grouped.collect { year, yGroup ->
        [ yearValue: year, monthList: yGroup.collect { month, mGroup ->
            [ monthValue: month, dateList: mGroup.collect { date, dGroup ->
                [ dateValue: date, events: dGroup ]
            } ]
        } ]
    }
]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I may have made a small mistake some where in here but I think this what you want:

```
def yearList = []
groupedResults.each{ year , month ->
    def dateList = []
    month.each{ date , events
        def eventList = []
        events.each{ event ->
            eventList.add([ eventTitle: event.evenName, eventStartDatetime: event.eventStartDateTime])
        }
        def eventMap = [:]
        eventMap.put("dateValue": date)
        eventMap.put ("events": eventList)
        dateList.add(eventMap)
    }
    dateMap  =[:]
    dateMap.put("dateList": dateList)
    dateMap.put("monthValue": month)
    yearList.add(["yearValue": year, "monthList": dateMap])
}
yearMap = [:]
yearMap.put("yearList": yearList)
```

I didn't get a chance to test so like I said I may have made a small mistake but you should get the idea.